# SQL update previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have a table which has the task records of all employees. The required spent hours is 9.5 (excluding lunchbreak) per day, whatever exceeds on that will be in the unpaidspent column.

Before, we used to leave the lunch as blank but now as they required to have the lunch as a task, the hour/minutes located on that lunchbreak is being included in the 9.5 required spenthours. Now:

1. How to move the breaktime value from spent to unpaid?
2. After the update, How can we deduct the breaktime unpaid to the last task unpaid and move it to the spenthours to complete the required 9.5 spent hours per day?
   Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky task, and there's a good chance that performance will be poor if your table includes many records. If that is the case, then you may consider running the update in batches by a field that partitions your table (`UserId` ?).

Assuming your table is called `#taskRecord`, first copy the time spent on breaks into the `UnpaidSpent` field and then set the `SpentHours` to `0` for breaks:

```
Update #taskRecord
   Set UnpaidSpent = SpentHours
   Where TaskName = 'Break Time';

Update #taskRecord
   Set SpentHours = 0
   Where TaskName = 'Break Time';
```

Then we'll need to identify rows which are the first row each day where there is unpaid time (excluding lunch break rows). If we have not already accumulated 9.5 paid hours for the day then move some of the time from the unpaid to the paid column.

```
With runningTotalHours As (
    Select UserID, WorkDateTime = WorkDate, WorkDate = Convert(date, WorkDate),  SpentHours, UnpaidSpent, TaskName,
        Sum(SpentHours + UnpaidSpent) Over (Partition By UserId, Convert(date, WorkDate) 
                                            Order By WorkDate
                                            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) As RunningTotalAll,
        Sum(SpentHours) Over (Partition By UserId, Convert(date, WorkDate)
                              Order By WorkDate
                              Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) As RunningTotalPaid
      from #taskRecord
      Where TaskName <> 'Break Time'),
RowsWithUnpaidHours As (
    Select UserID, WorkDateTime, WorkDate, SpentHours, UnpaidSpent, TaskName, RunningTotalAll, RunningTotalPaid,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By UserId, WorkDate Order By WorkDateTime) As RowNo
      From runningTotalHours
      Where UnpaidSpent <> 0)
Update RowsWithUnpaidHours
   Set SpentHours = CASE WHEN RunningTotalAll < 9.5 Then SpentHours + UnpaidSpent
                         ELSE SpentHours + 9.5 - RunningTotalPaid END,
    UnpaidSpent = CASE WHEN RunningTotalAll < 9.5 Then 0
                       ELSE UnpaidSpent - 9.5 + RunningTotalPaid END
   Where RowNo = 1 And RunningTotalPaid <> 9.5;
```

To ensure consistency, this only updates the very first row for each day with unpaid time. But there might be days where a person worked on multiple tasks during unpaid time at the end of the day which would now be considered paid after their lunch time was removed. So it is necessary to run the above statement multiple times until it reports `(0 row(s) affected)` which shows there are no more adjustments to be made.

Comment: @SongJoongKi01 great to hear that it worked. For the sake of completeness and to help future readers, could you mark the answer as Accepted if it fully answers your question?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE Your_table_name SET unpaid = spent
WHERE unpaid = 0 AND TaskName = 'Break Time'
```

Comment: `WHERE TaskName = 'Break Time'`